# Undefined method name for nil:NilClass

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having this problem for too long now and I can't find out where is the problem, so:

```
    Showing /home/alex/Desktop/personal/app/views/entries/list.html.erb where line #17 raised:

    undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #17):

14:   <% @entries.each do |entry| %>
15:   <tr>
16:   <td><%= link_to entry.title, :action => "show", :id => entry.id %></td>
17:   <td><%= link_to entry.category.name, :action => "list", :category_id => entry.category.id %></td>
18:   </tr>
19:   <% end %> 
20:
```

My views/entries/list.html.erb looks looks like this:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>All Entries</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1>Online Personal Collection- All Entries</h1>
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
  <td width="80%"><p align="center"><i><b>Entry</b></i></td> 
   <td width="20%"><p align="center"><i><b>Category</b></i></td>
  </tr>

  <% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= link_to entry.title, :action => "show", :id => entry.id %></td>
  <td><%= link_to entry.category.name, :action => "list", :category_id => entry.category.id %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %> 


  </table>
  <p><%= link_to "Create new entry", :action => "new" %></p>
   <br />
   <%=link_to "Back to Index", entries_path%>
   <br />
   <%=link_to "Back to Account Info", my_account_path%>
   <br />
   <h3>Enter keyword</h3>
<form action ="search" method="post">
<input name = "key" type="input" />
<input value="Send" type="submit"/>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

The models are like this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :comments, :date, :description, :title, :category_id, :category_name
  belongs_to :category
after_create do |entry|
      logger.info "entry created: #{entry.title} #{entry.description}"
end
end




class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :entries
end
```

And the entries_controller :

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /entries
  # GET /entries.json
  def index

    @entries = Entry.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @entries }
    end
  end

  def list
      if params[ :category_id].nil?
                  @entries = Entry.find(:all)
          else
              @entries = Entry.find(:all ,
                                :conditions => ["category_id = ?" , params[ :category_id]])
                   params[ :category_id] = nil

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # list.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @entry }
    end
  end
  end


  # GET /entries/1
  # GET /entries/1.json
  def show
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    @category = Category.find(:all)


   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @entry }
    end
  end

  # GET /entries/new
  # GET /entries/new.json
  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
    @categories= Category.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @entry }
    end
  end

  # GET /entries/1/edit
  def edit
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.find(:all)
  end

  # POST /entries
  # POST /entries.json
  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @entry, status: :created, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /entries/1
  # PUT /entries/1.json
```

Now if someone spot the problem and could help me understand where I'm doing wrong I will be grateful. 
Thanks! 
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an entry without a category, so `entry.category` is nil, so `entry.category.name` (in this instance) is `nil.name`, which makes no sense. It's generally good practice to avoid chaining methods on associations like this because of this very issue.

Rails has built-in delegation that you could use to prevent this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  delegate :name, to: :category, prefix: :category, allow_nil: true
end
```

This defines the `entry.category_name` instance method. In your view, if no category exists for that entry, nothing would appear there. You can read more about the delegation methods and options [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

**UPDATE:**

So I ignored the fact that you're trying to link to a nil object, when probably what you really want to do is not display the link at all when the object is nil. There's a [`link_to_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) method (that I've never used, but would probably work for you):

```
<%= link_to_if(entry.category, entry.category_name, :action => "list", :category_id => entry.category.id %>
```

You still need to use the `category_name` delegate method, because the name is printed (without the link) when the first argument evaluates to false.

Comment: Appreciate that but either i don't understand what you are saying to me or is not working. I get this: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id Extracted source (around line #17): 16: <td><%= link_to entry.title, :action => "show", :id => entry.id %></td> 17: <td><%= link_to entry.category_name, :action => "list", :category_id => entry.category.id %></td> 18: </tr> 19: <% end %> I changed the model as you said and this: <td><%= link_to entry.category_name, :action => "list", :category_id => entry.category.id %></td>

Comment: Well, you're getting the same error now, but on `entry.category.id`. One minute, I'll see if I can edit my answer to be more helpful.

Comment: There should be an extra end right? Cause it gives me a syntax error:

/home/alex/Desktop/personal/app/views/entries/list.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
');   end  
         

Extracted source (around line #20):

17:   <td><%= link_to_if(entry.category, entry.category_name, :action => "list", :category_id => entry.category.id %></td>
18:   
19:   </tr>
20:   <% end %> 
21:   
22:   
23:   </table>